# Bash- Storing key value in variables declared in Associative Array

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to create an associative array in bash containing the name of a file (a video) and its duration. The code is :

```
#!/bin/sh

shopt -s nullglob
movie=(*.mp4)

declare -A MYMAP[$filename]=${duration}

total=${#movie[*]}

for (( i=0; i<=$(( $total -1 )); i++ ))
do

MYMAP[duration]=10
MYMAP[filename]=${movie[i]}
echo "${MYMAP[@]}"
echo "${!MYMAP[@]}"

done

echo "${#MYMAP[@]}"
```

I want to pass the filename and store it in the key variable, and the duration in the value variable.
The duration will actually be queried through ffprobe, but that is immaterial at this point because the values are not being passed into the variables correctly.

The results are :

```
$ sh test2.sh
test2.sh: line 6: MYMAP[]: bad array subscript
10 File_01.mp4
duration filename
10 File_02.mp4
duration filename
10 File_03.mp4
duration filename
10 File_04.mp4
duration filename
10 File_05.mp4
duration filename
2
```

The duration and the filename both seem to be getting into the value, and key seems to be just outputting the variable names. Also if I declare the array this way:

```
declare -A MYMAP=[$filename]=${duration}
```

although it removes the warning it still outputs garbage.

Comment: The error in line 6 is because it should be `declare -A MYMAP`. The line `MYMAP[duration]=10` is creating an index with `duration` string, no the value of `$duration`, as well line `MYMAP[filename]=...`. The variables `$duration` and `$filename` are not  declared, are they available to the script? (edit- xenoid beat me to it while I was slowly writing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had not been able to articulate my problem, and perhaps I should put it down to an [XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info/) What I wanted to do was to collect *filenames* of mp4 files and their *durations* in an associative array as key-value pairs, with *filenames* as keys and *durations* as values. I was approaching it completely in the wrong manner.

This seems to be a reasonable solution, where the movie filenames are read in and their durations probed at the same time and stored at one go.

Hope this helps someone.

```
 #!/bin/sh
    
    shopt -s nullglob
    
    declare -A DURATIONARR
    
    while IFS= read -r movie
    do 
    DURATIONARR[$movie]=$(ffprobe "$movie" 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' | \
    awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,)
    done< <(find . -name "*.mp4" -exec basename {} \;)
    
    printf "%s\n" "${!DURATIONARR[@]}" "${DURATIONARR[@]}" | pr -2t
    
    unset DURATIONARR
```

Comment: I don't see how your solution differs from mine...

Comment: @xenoid It doesn't differ in concept- which is why I upvoted your answer. It only differs in how the data is read in through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

And associative array use strings as indices to retrieve values. It works like a plain array where you use strings instead of integers to address the contents.

```
# Declare the array
declare -A durations

# Two movies
sw1="ANewHope.mp4"
sw2="EmpireStrikesBack.mp4"

# Store values
durations[$sw1]=3600
durations[$sw2]=7200

# Retrieve values
echo ${durations[$sw1]}
echo ${durations[$sw2]}

# The movies
echo ${!durations[@]}

# The durations
echo ${durations[@]}
```

Comment: Thanks @xenoid, but I think my problem was poorly articulated.